# How to use curl and php to post json data to api Database

Tags: php, json, curl, ftp

I am struggling to understand this error when i am trying to post the data the the 3rd party api database.

I have the $data here which i want to post with the curl and it is in json format.

```
<?php

$url = 'https://www.yourdomain.com/uploadproducts';
$api_key = 'nMUiKg/oj7xtq40'; 
$sec_key = 'Nf+NQ2/WyjohqXOF1';

    $data = '{"product_sku":"FLAFFA000","product_category":"Fifth Avenue","product_subcategory":"0","product_name":"Love Print Flats","product_url":"http://love-print-flats-857","product_description":"Solid Candy Color Cartoon Printed Big","price":"1850","age_group":"0","product_img":"media/catalog/product/f/l/flaffa0001pin38.jpg,media/catalog/product/f/l/flaffa0001pin38_a.jpg,media/catalog/product/f/l/flaffa0001pin38_b.jpg","product_stock":[{"38":"1.0000"}],"product_discount":"100","discount_start_date":"0","discount_end_date":"0","product_tags":["0"]}';


    //var_dump($data);

    $data_string ='scapi_key='.urlencode($api_key).'&scsecret_key='.urlencode($sec_key)."&products=".urlencode($data);

    $ch = curl_init($url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);                                                                     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_errno($ch))
    {
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    }
      curl_close($ch);
        $arr = json_decode($response, true);
    echo "<pre>$response</pre>";
        echo $arr;    
    ?>
```

When i m trying to execute this file with the url www.yourdomain.com/test.php i m getting the following error.

```
{"msg":"200 OK","success":"Successfully added 0","updated":"Successfully updated 0","error":"Errors found 14"}
Array
```

Then i have tried using the

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                         
     'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                      
    );
```

to my code above, and i m getting the following error

```
{"msg":"API key is missing","success":"Successfully added 0","updated":"Successfully updated 0"}
Array
```

I have also dumped the json data and have validated the json format,

```
string(943) "{"product_sku":"FLAFFA000","product_category":"Fifth Avenue","product_subcategory":"0","product_name":"Love Print Flats","product_url":"http://love-print-flats-857","product_description":"Solid Candy Color Cartoon Printed Big","price":"1850","age_group":"0","product_img":"media/catalog/product/f/l/flaffa0001pin38.jpg,media/catalog/product/f/l/flaffa0001pin38_a.jpg,media/catalog/product/f/l/flaffa0001pin38_b.jpg","product_stock":[{"38":"1.0000"}],"product_discount":"100","discount_start_date":"0","discount_end_date":"0","product_tags":["0"]}";
```

On researching more on this issue, i have gone through the document of curl codes and it say that Error 14 is **CURLE_FTP_WEIRD_227_FORMAT (14)
FTP servers return a 227-line as a response to a PASV command. If libcurl fails to parse that line, this return code is passed back.**

So as per the error shown, is there any possible solution with the curl error 14 or is there error in the code ? What can be the issue with **FTP**?

Any little help or hint would help me out.

Comment: You have to see the code that send you the response, the error is not in this code.

Comment: Hi @Maverick Can you let me know where can be the problem, i might not get the third party api, sine they have only given the api key, secret key and url only. What should be figured out ??

Comment: The 'product_img' is not an url but a relative path link, on which server are the images? Moreover, have you checked the third-api service's documentation? Maybe the error number doesn't represent the curl error.

Comment: The images are loaded on cdn , aws. I haven't checked the third party api as they will not be giving any docs . I have only received which parameters I needed to fetch from database.  N then ti convert to json. And post to the url given.

Comment: So, try with the complete url for the imgs